# Good WYSIWYG Math Expression Builder or WYSIWYG Plug in?

Tags: .net, math, symbols, notation

Anyone know of a good Math Expression builder for an online WYSIWIG. Ideally the user would be able to **easily create common math symbols/notations like summation, integrals, radicals, etc...** online, ideally in an existing editor.

I also need to be able host it (and ideally integrate it) in a .NET stack (IIS/Windows).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You may check the [MathML editor by Connections](http://cnx.org/matheditor) which

(works at the moment only with Firefox)

Comment: It's javascript only, so easy to integrate on the server side. The client side thing needs work, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a WYSIWYG editor, but if you haven't already, check out [ASCIIMathML](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimath.html).  IMO it does a good job of rendering mathematical equations from tex-like markup.